# Solving cyclic dependency due to APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a service `AuthenticationService` that loads `AngularFirestore`. The service is loaded in `RootComponent`. All app modules are lazy-loaded in `RootComponent` (it has the main `router-outlet`). Now there are many sub-modules that also load `AngularFirestore`.

I have to ensure that `AuthenticationService` is initialized (async stuff) before the components and modules are loaded up, so I have put it in `APP_INITIALIZER` provider. This causes **cyclic-dependency** `Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! AngularFirestore`.

If I don't put it in `APP_INITIALIZER` it works but the app runs without `AuthenticationService` being initialized.

Is there a way around this? *(besides adding `auth.initialize()` in all components)*

**App tree:**

```
AppComponent -> RootComponent(AuthenticationService) -> All Submodules(AuthenticationService, AngularFirestore)
```

```js
// constructor of AuthenticationService
constructor(
    private auth : AngularFireAuth,
    private remoteconfig : AngularFireRemoteConfig,
    private keepalive: Keepalive,
    private idle: Idle, 
    private toast : ToastService,
    private router : Router,
    private fs : AngularFirestore,
    private http : HttpClient,
)
```

```js
// providers in app.module.ts
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  multi: true,
  useFactory: authFactory,
  deps: [
    AuthenticationService
  ]
}
```

```js
// Factory for APP_INITIALIZER
export function authFactory(
  auth : AuthenticationService
) {
  return () : Promise<any> => auth.initialize();
}
```

Regards!

Comment: Didn't check your use-case in detail, but this usually happens because of the HTTP interceptors. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20203).

Comment: @LazarLjubenović unfortunately i am not using any HTTP interceptors. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after going through a plethora of github comments and unrelated SO questions I came up with a solution that I skimmed through for an unrelated issue in Github comments.

**TLDR**: Make injection by creating a new service for `AngularFirestore` just for `AuthenticationService` or for the whole app. I went with the latter.

**Understanding the problem:**

*From what I understand*, the issue is because my `AuthenticationService` loads `AngularFirestore` and makes it part of its dependency tree. Now any subsequent injection of `AuthenticationService` and `AngularFirestore` makes a cyclic dependency, because injecting `AuthenticationService` makes `AngularFirestore` part of the dependency tree, and when I inject `AngularFirestore` after that it creates two injections of `AngularFirestore`. Hence the error. I may be completely wrong, but I think this was the issue.

**Solution:**

Create a service for `AngularFirestore` import. This, I think, moves it out of the dependency tree and injects it as a service making it OK for any subsequent injections of `AngularFirestore` safe.

```js
// appfirestoreservice.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppFirestoreService {
  
  public fs : AngularFirestore;
  public readonly collection = this._fs.collection;
  public readonly doc = this._fs.doc;
  public readonly createId = this._fs.createId;

  constructor(
    private _fs : AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    this.fs = _fs;
  }
}
```

```js
// App Initializer in AppModule
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  multi: true,
  useFactory: initFactory,
  deps: [
    AppServiceInitializerService,
    RemoteConfigService,
    AuthenticationService,
  ]
},
```

For my case I had to create a service just to load `RemoteConfigService` and `AuthenticationService` because they have to be initialized one after the other.

Regards!